# Can't Write from FileStream

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to get a byte[] from a `FileInfo`.

Here, The `FileInfo`(fi) is a file I drop into my silverlight app.

So, as found on msnd, I am doing this :

```
byte[] b = new byte[fi.Length];
                    UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
                //Open the stream and read it back.
                using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead())
                {

                    while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
                    {

                      Console.WriteLine(temp.GetString(b));
                    }
                }
```

But, do to it's protection level, I cannot use this.

So, I have done this :

```
            byte[] b = new byte[fi.Length];
            UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        //Open the stream and read it back.
        using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead())
        {

            while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            }
        }
```

But I got the message that I cannot Write from the `FileStream`.

Why I cannot write my File I drop into my app into a byte?
When The File is drop, it become a FileInfo.

Why I use `OpenRead()`? Because on the msdn, it seems it is writing the file : [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.fileinfo.openread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

`OpenWrite()` rise an access error also.

Is there another way to do get yhe FileInfo document, into a byte?

Comment: So you've open stream for reading only, but trying to write to it... What else do you expect - "can't write to R/O stream" seem to be reasonable behavior for me... Not sure what you trying to do overall - so you probably have something else in mind - consider adding your actual goal to the question.

Comment: Look: `fs = fi.OpenRead()`, `fs` is opened for reading, not for writing

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what I want is, write the File I drop (turn into FileInfo) into a byte.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean "into a byte"... You already reading whole file into byte array (may need improve reading code if it happen not to read in one call by adjusting offset on every read call, but for initial version it is ok)... But I'm lost what you are trying to do with the array afterwards.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Once I got my byte, I want to store in a object. And then, when I open the byte, I have a good document. But the doc isn't readable like this.

Comment: Have you tried http://blogpad-online.blogspot.com/2011/02/fileinfo-get-file-bytes.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a file into a byte[] the easies way would be:

```
 byte[] myByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(myFileInfo.FullName);
```

As @Dmitry Bychenko allready stated you try to write to a FileStream opened as readonly.
The other thing is that you want to write to the same FileStream you read from.

To solve the problem by correcting the attempt you did you can do:

```
byte[] b = new byte[fi.Length];
UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
//Open the stream and read it back.
using (FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead())
{
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b))
     {
         while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
         {
             ms.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
         }
     }
}
```

In your case i would vote for the first example as its simple to read and hides the stream stuff perfectly.

Comment: As I said in the question, it is a FileInfo, not File, so I don't have ReadAllBytes().

Comment: @Zaphod if you read my first example you will see that i used a FileInfo to get the path for the file to read.

Comment: yeah, but as I am in silverlight, I do not have. I am trying your second solution right now. Seeems it is working. The key is using a `memoryStream` then. Thank you.